# AtTiny85 and MMA8452Q accelerometer cannot connect using i2c

Tags: i2c, attiny, accelerometer

I am trying to connect the MMA8452Q with AtTiny85 using the TinyWireM library.
I made the proper hardware setup with  pull-ups on  SCL and SDA pins - tested it on Arduino
Uno and it works, however when i connect the Tiny I cannot even get the handshake.
The following code produces output `13` instead of `42` (0x2A)

**HARDWARE SETUP**

MMA8452 Breakout ------------AtTiny85

3.3V -------voltage regulator------ 5V

SDA -----------^^(330)^^----------- PB0 (on attiny programmer marked as 5)

SCL -----------^^(330)^^----------- PB3 (on attiny programmer marked as 2)

GND --------------------------------- GND

(I also tried different pins with no luck)

**CODE**

```
//---bluetooth console communication stuff---//
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define rxPin 1 //not important - needed for initialization
#define txPin A2
SoftwareSerial blueTooth(rxPin, txPin);
//      ---     //


#include "TinyWireM.h" // Used for I2C

// The SparkFun breakout board defaults to 1, set to 0 if SA0 jumper on the bottom of the board is set
#define MMA8452_ADDRESS 0x1D  // 0x1D if SA0 is high, 0x1C if low


#define WHO_AM_I   0x0D



void setup() {

  blueTooth.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  TinyWireM.begin(); //Join the bus as a master
  delay(1000);
 }

void loop() {
   byte c =0;
   c = readRegister(WHO_AM_I); 
   blueTooth.println(c); 
   delay(1000);
  }


 // Read a single byte from addressToRead and return it as a byte
byte readRegister(byte addressToRead) {
  TinyWireM.beginTransmission(MMA8452_ADDRESS);
  TinyWireM.send(addressToRead);
  TinyWireM.endTransmission(); //endTransmission but keep the connection active

  TinyWireM.requestFrom(MMA8452_ADDRESS, 1); //Ask for 1 byte, once done, bus is released by default

  while(!TinyWireM.available()) ; //Wait for the data to come back
  return TinyWireM.receive(); //Return this one byte
}
```

Would anyone know how to get it right?

Comment: I2C pullup resistors are 4.7 kohm to Vcc (at 5V). SCL is PB2 (chip pin 7) and SDA is PB0 (chip pin 5).

Comment: changed the resistors. still getting the same output

Answer (score 1):

On an ATtiny85 pin 5 (PB0) is SDA and pin 7 (PB2) is SCL for the I2C interface.  You're using the wrong pin for SCL.

Additionally, your pull-up resistors are too strong.  Somewhere between 4.7K Ohm and 10K Ohm are recommended for pull-up's on the SDA and SCL lines.

Answer (score 0):

> using the TinyWireM library.

Make sure the i2c actually works. Arduino libraries are generally of poor quality and just because someone wrote it doesn't mean it actually works. Get a logic analyzer or scope on the bus and see what's going on.

Once you can confirm that, get a datasheet for the 8452 and see how it works and code to it.

Comment: i tried doing  what you suggested and also tried pluging i2c  attiny as slave to uno as master. did not work either. 
Generally what i get on oscillator is some mess different than what i get when plugging uno.  On uno i get nice square waves on clock and digital signals on sda. i ran some tests and used the pb0 and pb2 and pb3 pins on attiny for serial communication so the pins work (i guess?). Could it still be the chip problem? It seems that  many folks succeed with using TinyWireM as i2c library... i dont know where to go from here

Comment: i scanned for i2c devices and it detects an i2c device at each address it scans... so weird